# Node.js fastify разработка сайта

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

Доброго времени суток!

Перехожу с ASP.NET на Node.js. На Node.js API все оказалось намного проще чем в ASP.NET но вот фронтенд сайта вызывает неопределенность. Очень много пакетов на котором все делают сайты к примеру express но мне нужно именно на fastify тк api была написана на нем и не хочется плодить основные библиотеки. В гугле не нашел ни одного примера сайта на fastify. И не очень понятна структура сайта на Node.js.

Как я понимаю express,fastify и прочие это основная часть приложения которая руководит всеми движениями проекта(роутинг, коннект, логика). И к нему подключаются отдельные модули в зависимости от цели. Если все верно, какая самая простая связка для реализации сайта вроде лендинга? Если есть ссылки на гайды или советы буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не имею опыта работы с .NET, поэтому не могу приводить аналогий.

Для разработки фронта есть 2 пути:

- Реализовать полноценное SPA, бекенд будет предоставлять API, а рендерить все будет отдельное приложение на Vue/React/Angular
- Подключить шаблонизатор и на каждом роуте рендерить соответствующий `view`

Для лендинга лучше подойдет вариант с шаблонизатором, рассмотрим его. 
Для начала подключаем модуль рендеринга [point-of-view](https://github.com/fastify/point-of-view) через npm: `npm install point-of-view --save`

Он поддерживает следующие шаблонизаторы:

- [ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs)
- [ejs-mate](https://github.com/JacksonTian/ejs-mate)
- [nunjucks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks)
- [pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug)
- [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars)
- [marko](https://github.com/marko-js/marko)
- [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)
- [art-template](https://github.com/aui/art-template)

При регистрации модуля указывается выбранный шаблонизатор, приведу пример из репозитория:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.register(require('point-of-view'), {
  engine: {
    ejs: require('ejs') // подключаем шаблонизатор ejs
  }
})

fastify.get('/', (req, reply) => { // при GET запросе /
  reply.view('/templates/index.ejs', { text: 'text' }) // рендерим view index.ejs и пробрасываем туда переменную text со значением "текст"
})
```

Как правило, у каждого шаблона свой синтаксис, нужно будет посмотреть каждый и подобрать по вкусу.

В дополнение рекомендую прочитать [Node.js Best Practices](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но все же я буду копать в сторону первого варианта. тк api я уже вынес отдельно. У меня есть [пример](https://github.com/cosmicjs/simple-blog). там используется express, некоторые библиотеки на котором построен форум не работает на fastify. Уж очень удобное строение проекта. Хотелось бы что-то подобное но на fastify